# how to auto update mongodb field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a `Category` schema and I want when `children` field changes to check its length and if the length is equal to 0 then `has_children` should be `false` and the opposite should apply.

This is my model :

```
const category_item = new mongoose.Schema({

   //...other fields...,
   children: { type: Array, required: true, default: [] }
   has_children:  // if children length equal to 0 get false and opposite     
});
```

Comment: Is it possible for has_children to equal true, then later be equal false?  If not, I would say just set has_children to false when you create a new user, and then when you add a child or create a new user with a child set has_children to true then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep

```
const category_item = new mongoose.Schema({

    ...anotherFields...,
    children : {type : Array , required : true , default : []}
    has_children : {type: Boolean}
});
```

and add a pre save hook

```
category_item.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.children && this.children.length > 0) {
        this.has_children = true;
    } else {
        this.has_children = false;
    }
    next();
});
```

**Reference:** http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html